# Facebook Graph API: Any constrains to the query string length when making a GET request to https://graph.facebook.com/?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, http-get

Does anybody know if there are any constraints to the query string length when making a GET request to Facebook graph API? So far I've not encountered any problems but it's very important to know if there are any constraints or limitations.

Thanks,
-Ali

Answer (score 0):

From a comment from the Paging section of the Facebook API docs: *it is helpful to know that the maximum number of results we will fetch before running the visibility checks is 5,000*. That was for FQL, but I'm assuming the same limits apply to the Graph API. So you can't get more than 5000 results at a time

Comment: I'm retrieving basic information about friends. There is no limit to the number of friends at Facebook (at least as far as I know) and this can make the query string arbitrarily long. The query string length is considerably different for someone who has fifty friends than someone who has five thousand friends. For someone with five thousand friends for example, probably I should make more than one GET requests, but I was trying to figure out what would be a good threshold for the number of friend IDs to put in a single query. After all you would want to make as less queries as possible.

Comment: Ah, quite true that you want to make as few queries as possible, but I'm pretty sure you can't ask for multiple friends' info at the same time using the Graph API: looking at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/ I see no way to change the query depending on the number of friends you have. I'd be very interested in seeing what one of the Graph API URLs you are using that requests multiple friends' info looks like.

Comment: You can actually and I've been doing this. Here is a copy paste from http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

"You can also request multiple objects in a single query using the 'ids' query parameter. For example, the URL https://graph.facebook.com?ids=arjun,vernal returns both profiles in the same response."

Instead of 'arjun' or 'vernal' above you can also use their corresponding numeric IDs. Imagine how long this query string would be if you were requesting information about friends of someone who has five thousand connections :-)

Comment: So it is, and I could see as how that would be an issue. I will have to use that capability someday soon. What I think you really want is this comment from the Paging section: **it is helpful to know that the maximum number of results we will fetch before running the visibility checks is 5,000.**. That was for FQL, but I'm assuming the same limits apply to the Graph API. So you can't get more than 5000 results at a time. Tha

Comment: Thanks a lot. @forum.developers.facebook.net I was told the following: "there is a limit on the query string length, as GET request to Facebook graph API is just a HTTP GET request." Apparently there is a constraint. AFAIK the specifications of HTTP Get live this open and any constraint would be implementation dependent. By the way, all RESTFull interfaces I'm familiar with, support retrieving information about multiple records with one call (e.g. LinkedIn, Hyves).